# Is there good way to get title tag of some other domain page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Like this :

If I'm using jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://www.google.com',  
        //some other domain like 'https://facebook.com', Not of my domain that I can control.
        type:'get',
        dataType:'html',
        cache:false,
        success:function (data) {
            var headline = data;
            alert(data);
            $('#div_test').html(data.get_title_tag)
        }
    });
```

Let me say target url : http://example.com

I googled for a day, and found these.

1. Iframe

Is it possible, if http://example.com does not allow Iframe access?

As I searched, It's impossible when http://example.com does not allows Iframe access.

2. Server control

I post http://example.com url data to my server on my `url_post_page`, and server will do url request stuff, and return data to my `url_post_page`.

**Question :**

But I want to get `<title>title</title>` value of `http://example.com` just on client using Javascript or jQuery.

Is there any good way of this things?

Comment: no, you can not do such a thing directly from a browser - same origin restrictions prevent this for security reasons

Comment: i am just curious to know the reason for doing so..coz in many occasions the title likely going to have values as "Main" ,"Home" and so on..what you are willing to extract?

Comment: @RohitS I wanted it for my bookmark app study. But what a pity of security reasons. Thanks for your comments.